# Firebird Interbase Connection - unset() and ibase_close()

Tags: php, database-connection, firebird, unset, interbase

I have a silly question.
Is there a difference between unset() and ibase_close() in terms of ending connection to Firebird Database using ibase_connect()?
I know that some people use unset() to PDO connections etc.

Like:

```
$connection = ibase_connect(SOME PARAMETERS HERE);
```

And then:

```
unset($connection);
```

or

```
ibase_close($connection);
```

If they both are behaving the same, maybe one function is faster than the other one?

Comment: By common sense it is the difference between destroying object and freeing memory (latter) and losing reference and leaking memory (former). However there might be some automagic tricks like ARC inside PHP or PDO, who knows? Actually don't ask what you can see by your own eyes! Hope you have Firebird 2.5 or newer, the one that has TraceAPI. Take a program like http://FBprofiler.sf.net or IBExpert Personal, set trace filters to include connect/disconnect events, start logging - and see if `unset` would result in disconnect event on FB server or not.

Comment: i guess intended use was like `$conn2 = $connection;  unset($connection); ....do something else in other subroutines....  ibase_close($conn2); unset($conn2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge of PHP is rudimentary at best, but as far as I know there is a distinct difference.

The function `ibase_close($connection)` will send a message to the database server, so the server releases its connection resources and then it closes the connection, while `unset($connection)` will only delete the variable `$connection`.

My knowledge of PHP and the firebird-php/interbase driver is not sufficient to know for sure if using `unset` will trigger a cleanup or close of the connection, but a quick scan of the firebird-php sources doesn't show any such mechanism. My suggestion is that you should be explicit and use `ibase_close` **before** you call `unset`, so you're sure resources (including serverside resources) are released properly.

Answer (score 0):

**ibase_close** closes the non-persistent connection to the server that's associated with $connection. Default transaction on link is committed, other transactions are rolled back.

**unset** clears the pointer to the instance.